# Merge two dataframes on value in column of df1 in comma separated values in column of df2 AND df1.Column2 = df2.Column2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Input: two dataframes having the following values:

df1:

```
| Employee Name | EmployeeID | workDate   |
|---------------|------------|------------|
| John          | 2,22       | 2020-11-01 |
| John          | 2,22       | 2020-11-02 |
| Kim           | 3          | 2020-11-01 |
```

df2:

```
| EmployeeID | workDate   | Hours |
|------------|------------|-------|
| 2          | 2020-11-01 | 8     |
| 22         | 2020-11-02 | 2     |
| 3          | 2020-11-01 | 10    |
```

Need to join these two dataframes on df2.EmployeeID in df1.EmployeeIDs AND df2.workDate == df1.workDate.

Output:

```
| Employee Name | EmployeeID | workDate   | Hours |
|---------------|------------|------------|-------|
| John          | 2,22       | 2020-11-01 | 8     |
| John          | 2,22       | 2020-11-02 | 2     |
| Kim           | 3          | 2020-11-01 | 10    |
```

Comment: df2 = pd.merge(df,df1,on = ['EmployeeID','workDate'], how = 'outer')

Comment: wouldn't work. df1.EmployeeID is a comma separated field of multiple employeeID's. df2.EmployeeID has only one of those employeeID's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) with splitted values by `,`, then use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join and last aggregate back by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
#converted to strings for match splitted values
df2['EmployeeID'] = df2['EmployeeID'].astype(str)

    
df1 = (df1.assign(EmployeeID = df1['EmployeeID'].str.split('\s*,\s*'))
          .explode('EmployeeID')
          .merge(df2, on=['EmployeeID','workDate'], how='left')
          .groupby(['Employee Name','workDate'], as_index=False, sort=False)
          .agg({'EmployeeID':','.join, 'Hours':'sum'}))
print (df1)
  Employee Name    workDate EmployeeID  Hours
0          John  2020-11-01       2,22    8.0
1          John  2020-11-02       2,22    2.0
2           Kim  2020-11-01          3   10.0
```

Comment: I think we need to strip values in EmployeeID
so it would become something like:
df1.assign(EmployeeID = df1["EmployeeID"].str.split(",").apply(lambda row: [value.strip() for value in row])

right?

Comment: @programming_ocd - Or simplier `df1['EmployeeID'].str.split(',')` change to `df1['EmployeeID'].str.split(' ,')` it means `','` is changed to `' ,'`

Comment: yea, true. EmployeeID is a user inputted field. So I cannot always guarantee if they have a space or not :/

Comment: @programming_ocd - Ok, so use regex like `'\s*,'` it means zero or more spaces and ,

Comment: yep will try to hehe
Question: df1.assign(EmployeeID... means we are replacing the current employeeID correct?
Is it the same as:
df1["EmployeeID"] = df1["EmployeeID"].str.split(",").apply(lambda row: [value.strip() for value in row])

Comment: @programming_ocd - yes, it is same.

Comment: final result: df1.assign(EmployeeID = df1["EmployeeID"].str.split('\s*,\s*')  --caters for leading and trailing spaces